# SSJS Restrict Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Is there any SSJS function that would allow me to restrict a contact? (I can't find anything related in the documentation)

Ref: /contacts/v1/contacts/actions/restrict?type=keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using HTTPost to make an api call, there is not a function to restrict contacts.